# Tamaño de vista a su contenido en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

¿Cómo podría adaptar el tamaño de una View, al contenido que posee?

Por ejemplo, una View que contenga una label. Esta label en un primer momento dice: "*Hola*".
Pero puede darse el caso que diga: "*hastaluego*". Y el tamaño aumente.

Lo que me gustaría es que esa View que lo contiene, ajuste su tamaño para que sea igual que el de esa label.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es ajustar el tamaño del label de acuerdo a la longitud. Puedes agregar esta línea:

```
self.tuLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Además debes agregar las constraint del label al View.

Comment: De acuerdo, entonces lo ideal es hacerlo por código no? No hay nada en la interfaz de XCODE que te facilite eso.

Comment: En la interfaz de Xcode no, no sé porque Apple no las agrega.

Answer (score 0):

Si esta trabajando en el storyboard esto se puede hacer, pero tiene que tener cuidado que no haya alguna constrain limitando el ancho de la view.

- No pongas restricciones de ancho a la View (esas las marcara la label).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Una vez cambie la label, la View crecerá para poder mantener la misma distancia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]